# Vue- best practice for loops and event handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am curious if it is better to include `methods` within loops instead of using `v-if`. Assume the following codes work (they are incomplete and do not)

**EX: Method**

```html
<template >
    <div>
        <div v-for="(d, i) in data" v-bind:key="i">
            <span v-on:click="insertPrompt($event)">
                {{ d }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        data:[
            .....
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        insertPrompt(e){
            body.insertBefore(PROMPT)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The DOM would be updated via the `insertPrompt()` function which is just for display

**EX: V-IF**

//Parent

```html
<template >
    <div>
        <div v-for="(d, i) in data" v-bind:key="i">
            <child v-bind:data="d"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './child'

export default {
    components:{
        child
    },
    data() {
        data:[
            .....
        ]
    },
}
</script>
```

//Child

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-on:click="display != display">
            {{ d }}
        </span>
        <PROMPT v-if="display"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './child'

export default {
    components:{
        child
    },
    data(){
        return {
            display:false
        }
    },
    props: {
        data:{
            .....
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

The `PROMPT` is a basic template that is rendered with the data from the loop data click.

Both methods can accomplish the same end result. My initial thought is having additional conditions within a loop would negatively impact performance?!?!

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: This really depends on what's in `PROMPT`. Does it need to display reactive content? Does it need to communicate with other components? I'd lean towards the second option where everything is controlled by Vue but this is pretty subjective

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are rendering really huge amounts of items in your loops (and most of the times you don't), you don't need to worry about performance at all. Any differences will be so small nobody will ever notice / benefit from having it a tiny touch faster.

The second point I want to make is that doing your own DOM manipulations is often not the best idea: [Why do modern JavaScript Frameworks discourage direct interaction with the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028064/why-do-modern-javascript-frameworks-discourage-direct-interaction-with-the-dom)

So I would in any case stick with the `v-if` for conditionally rendering things. If you want to care about performance / speed here, you might consider what exactly is the way your app will be used and decide between `v-if` and `v-show`. Citing the official documentation:

> `v-if` is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event
> listeners and child components inside the conditional block are
> properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> `v-if` is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it
> will not do anything - the conditional block won’t be rendered until
> the condition becomes true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, `v-show` is much simpler - the element is always rendered
> regardless of initial condition, with CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, `v-if` has higher toggle costs while v-show has
> higher initial render costs. So prefer `v-show` if you need to toggle
> something very often, and prefer `v-if` if the condition is unlikely to
> change at runtime.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous solutions to solving this issue, but let's stick to 3. Options 2 and 3 are better practices, but option 1 works and Vue was designed for this approach even if hardcore developers might frown, but stick yoru comfort level.

**Option 1: DOM Manipulation**

Your data from a click, async, prop sets a condition for v-if or v-show and your component is shown. Note v-if removes the DOM element where v-show hides the visibility but the element is still in the flow. If you remove the element and add its a complete new init, which sometimes works in your favor when it come to reactivity, but in practice try not to manipulate t*he DOM as that will always be more expensive then loops, filters, maps, etc.*

```
<template >
    <div>
        <div v-for="(d, i) in getData" 
             :key="i">
            <div v-if="d.active">
                <child-one></child-one>
            </div>
            <div v-else-if="d.active">
                <child-two></child-two>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import ChildOne from "./ChildOne";
    import ChildTwo from "./ChildTwo";

    export default {
        components: {
            ChildOne,
            ChildTwo
        },
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
            }
        },
        computed: {
            getData() {
                return this.data;
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            // assume thsi woudl come from async but for now ..
            this.data = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    comp: 'ChildOne',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    comp: 'ChildTwo',
                    active: true
                },
            ];
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Option 2: Vue's `<component>` component**

Always best to use Vue built in component  Vue’s  element with the `is` special attribute: `<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>`

In this example we pass a slug or some data attribute to activate the component. Note we have to load the components ahead of time with the `components: {},` property for this to work i.e. it has to be ChildOne or ChildTwo as slug string. This is often used with tabs and views to manage and maintain states.

The advantage of this approach is if you have 3 form tabs and you enter data on one and jump to the next and then back the state / data is maintained, unlike v-if where everything will be rerendered / lost.

Vue

```
<template >
    <div>
        <component :is="comp"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ChildOne from "./ChildOne";
    import ChildTwo from "./ChildTwo";

    export default {
        components: {
            ChildOne,
            ChildTwo
        },
        props: ['slug'],
        data() {
            return {
                comp: 'ChildOne',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setComponent () {
                // assume prop slug passed from component or router is one of the components e.g. 'ChildOne'
                this.comp = this.slug;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.nextTick(this.setModule())
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Option 3: Vue & Webpack Async and Dynamic components.**

When it comes to larger applications or if you use Vuex and Vue Route where you have dynamic and large number of components then there are a number of approaches, but I'll stick to one. Similar to option 2, we are using the component element, but we are using WebPack to find all Vue files recursively with the keyword 'module'. We then load these dynamically / asynchronous --- meaning they will only be loaded when needed and you can see this in action in network console of browser. This means I can build components dynamically (factory pattern) and render them as needed. Example, of this might be if a user adds projects and you have to build and config views dynamically for projects created e.g. using vue router you passed it a ID for a new project, then you would need to dynamically load an existing component or build and load a factory built one.

Note: I'll use v-if on a component element if I have many components and I'm unsure the user will need them. I don't want to maintain state on large collections of components because I will end up memory and with loads of observers / watches / animations will most likely end up with CPU issues

```
<template >
    <div>
        <component :is="module" v-if="module"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const requireContext = require.context('./', true, /\.module\.vue$/);
    const modules = requireContext.keys()
        .map(file =>
            [file.replace(/(.*\/(.+?)\/)|(\.module.vue$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
        )
        .reduce((components, [name, component]) => {
            // console.error("components", components)
            components[name] = component.default || component
            return components
        }, {});

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                module: [],
            }
        },
        props: {
            slug: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            getData() {
                return this.data;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            setModule () {
                let module = this.slug;

                if (!module || !modules[module]) {
                    module = this.defaultLayout
                }

                this.module = modules[module]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.nextTick(this.setModule())
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

> My initial thought is having additional conditions within a loop would negatively impact performance?

I think you might be confused by [this rule](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) in the style guide that says:

> Never use `v-if` on the same element as `v-for`.

It's only a style issue if you use `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element. For example:

```
<div v-for="user in users" v-if="user.isActive">
```

But it's not a problem if you use `v-if` in a "child" element of a `v-for`. For example:

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <div v-if="user.isActive">
```

Using `v-if` wouldn't have a more negative performance impact than a method. And I'm assuming you would have to do some conditional checks inside your method as well. Remember that even calling a method has some (very small) performance impact.

Once you use Vue, I think it's a good idea not to mix it up with JavaScript DOM methods (like `insertBefore`). Vue maintains a virtual DOM which helps it to figure out how best to update the DOM when your component data changes. By using JavaScript DOM methods, you won't be taking advantage of Vue's virtual DOM anymore.

By sticking to Vue syntax you also make your code more understandable and probably more maintainable other developers who might read or contribute to your code later on.